# Using `$geometry` causes Formula to None in Field Calculator within the QGIS modeler

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgis-modeler

So I have a simple model with a vector layer as input. I want to create a new field with the Field Calculator named Azimuth:
[image: Adding field]

But when I run the model I get:
[image: Formula None]

As you can see the `FORMULA`is None. As a test I tried to change the expression to `degrees( azimuth( start_point(  geom_from_wkt( 'POINT(4 5)' ) ), end_point(  geom_from_wkt( 'POINT(4 9)' ) ) ) )` (swapping the `$geometry` to `geom_from_wkt( 'POINT(4 5)'`) which works as expected.

The `$geometry` works fine on the same layer when I run it in the Field calculator in QGIS, what am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried using the `value` option instead of the `pre-calcoled value` ?

Comment: I see you are using QGIS 3.16 but did you create the model with the same version ? 
I tried on QGIS 3.22 and it's working like a charm !

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurred since I used a temporary layer as input, when I used a layer stored as shapefile it worked like expected!